# Get Current TimeStamp

Tags: rust, timestamp, clock, solana

I am working on the Solana contract with rust language and faced one critical problem.

In order to get current Unix timestamp, I used `SystemTime` like below.

```rust
let current_timestamp: i64 = SystemTime::now()
        .duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH)
        .unwrap()
        .as_secs() as i64;
```

Btw, the client asking to not to use `SystemTime` because it waste too many compute unit.
For this problem, I used `BpfClock` but it doesn't pass the unit test.

```rust
let clock = BpfClock::get()?;
let current_timestamp: i64 = clock.unix_timestamp;
```

The unit test result below error message:

```
thread 'processor::tests::test_withdraw' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: UnsupportedSysvar'
```

Comment: where does bfpclock comes from?

Comment: "Btw, the client asking to not to use SystemTime because it waste too many compute unit." nani ?

Comment: @Netwave Bfpclock is the same as Clock in solana_program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  On-chain, you do not have access to the system time, only utilities that are exposed by the runtime, so `SystemTime::now()` will completely fail on-chain.  You can read more about these restrictions at https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/developing-rust#restrictions

To access the clock, you are doing the right thing, but you must be runing in some sort of runtime-like environment for this to work.  This could be fully on-chain or through `solana_program_test`, which gives access to utilities such as `Clock`.  You can see a working example of using the Clock on-chain at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/examples/rust/sysvar

Be sure to run the tests using `cargo test-bpf` from the Solana CLI -- you can find the installation instructions at https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

Comment: **Jon Cinque**.  
Thank you so much for your answer. It's so helpful for me.

Could you please let me know if it's okay that I use Clock::clone() as clock obj?

Comment: Yes, it's totally supported, so go for it!