# Getting UnsupportedSysvar error trying to get a Clock instance

Tags: rust, runtime, solana

I am trying to get a Clock obj from within a rust client as below (simplified version), but I am getting the error `UnsupportedSysvar`. Is it possible to call this?

This is a simplified version of what I tried:

```
use solana_program::clock::Clock;

fn get_clock() -> Clock {
  let clock = Clock::get().unwrap();
  clock
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about solana but does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69596360/get-current-timestamp

Comment: I did manage to get something working based on the code in the repo posted on the linked post, so thank you